# Genomic instability of cancer cells in h&e image

Tags: cancer, microscopy, staining, image-processing

Is there are any books or papers on the topic of visual differences(analyzing H&E microscopy) of high grade cancer cells vs low grade cancer cells vs non-cancer cells?

In particular, I am trying to measure how much of genome was altered by analyzing images.

Comment: That seems like a substantial undertaking.  How familiar are you with histopathology generally?  The identification and grading of tumors is a large topic in histopathology, about which a good deal has been written (to my knowledge, none on your question specifically, but I am by no means an expert in pathology). Are you looking at a particular type of neoplasm?

Comment: @Hans you are absolutely right, this is a very challenging problem. I am CS major and have some datasets and interesting algorithms that I am going to apply, but first I wanted to get at least a little bit of understanding of the field. I read some articles about histopathology and this was useful and insightful, but I decided to ask this here in case anyone can give me some pointers to more relevant books on this topic. I am looking at a prostate cancer, but I believe general principles are the same -- I read that some mutated cells change shape\function\invade tissues and blood vessels\etc

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpreting your question. Tumor grading would be done histologically. To determine alterations to the genome itself, I would think that the only thing you could do visually is karyotyping. You could get a sense of translocations, loss of chromosomes, indels, etc. Otherwise you would likely need to do sequencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histologic diagnosis of tumors is made using the so-called  [WHO blue books](http://www.iarc.fr/en/publications/pdfs-online/pat-gen/).

Different tumors show different patterns of cellular and tissual aberrations.

On h&e  [karyorrexis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karyorrhexis) and  [pyknosis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyknosis)  are examples histological markers of nuclear aberration.

A recent  [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19894267) reviews the salient visual and subvisual morphological changes of cancer nuclei and their possible cause or [*etiology*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiology) and significance.